# APK/APP installed during macrobenchmark crashes on launch

Tags: android, performance, gradle, benchmarking, macrobenchmark

I am trying to setup macrobenchmarking on my app which has multiple modules and multiple flavors and following the android developer guide. However, I am getting below error related to DROP_SHADER_CACHE even though I have added profileInstaller dependency on the target app.

```
com.example.macrobenchmark.ExampleStartupBenchmark > startup[V2029 - 12] FAILED 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The DROP_SHADER_CACHE broadcast was not received. This most likely means that the `androidx.profileinstaller` library used by the target apk is old. Please use `1.3.0-alpha02` or newer. For more information refer to the release notes at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/profileinstaller.
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkScope.dropShaderCache(MacrobenchmarkScope.kt:286)
```

I am using Android Gradle Plugin v7.3.0 and Profile Installer v1.3.1

Below error comes while running benchmark tests.

> Execution failed for task
> ':macrobenchmark:connectedGpBenchmarkAndroidTest'

I have observed that APP installed as part of the above process crashes on launch. This might be the reason of above error.

Stacktrace of App Crash

```
2024-02-15 16:19:27.752  9069-9099  TestRunner              com.example.macrobenchmark           E  failed: startup(com.example.macrobenchmark.ExampleStartupBenchmark)
2024-02-15 16:19:27.752  9069-9099  TestRunner              com.example.macrobenchmark           E  ----- begin exception -----
2024-02-15 16:19:27.774  9069-9099  TestRunner              com.example.macrobenchmark           E  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The DROP_SHADER_CACHE broadcast was not received. This most likely means that the `androidx.profileinstaller` library used by the target apk is old. Please use `1.3.0-alpha02` or newer. For more information refer to the release notes at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/profileinstaller.
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkScope.dropShaderCache(MacrobenchmarkScope.kt:286)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:440)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:422)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmark$measurements$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:251)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmark$measurements$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:241)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.perfetto.PerfettoTraceProcessor$Companion.runServer(PerfettoTraceProcessor.kt:105)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmark(Macrobenchmark.kt:241)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode(Macrobenchmark.kt:422)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule.measureRepeated(MacrobenchmarkRule.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule.measureRepeated$default(MacrobenchmarkRule.kt:97)
                                                                                                        at com.example.macrobenchmark.ExampleStartupBenchmark.startup(ExampleStartupBenchmark.kt:30)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
                                                                                                        at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule$applyInternal$1.evaluate(MacrobenchmarkRule.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:136)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
                                                                                                        at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:162)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
                                                                                                        at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:67)
                                                                                                        at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
                                                                                                        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:446)
2024-02-15 16:19:27.774  9069-9099  TestRunner              com.example.macrobenchmark           E      at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2298)
2024-02-15 16:19:27.774  9069-9099  TestRunner              com.example.macrobenchmark           E  ----- end exception -----
2024-02-15 16:19:27.787  9069-9099  TestRunner              com.example.macrobenchmark           I  finished: startup(com.example.macrobenchmark.ExampleStartupBenchmark)
2024-02-15 16:19:27.796  9069-9099  TestRunner              com.example.macrobenchmark           I  run finished: 1 tests, 1 failed, 0 ignored
2024-02-15 16:19:44.858  9792-9792  AndroidRuntime          pid-9792                             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.app.myapp, PID: 9792
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.game.soulmate.MyApplication package com.app.myapp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.game.soulmate.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~J71UieQOQlumHrcdA8XIpg==/com.app.myapp-Jvagd_AD7yNyuIUNahByDQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~J71UieQOQlumHrcdA8XIpg==/com.app.myapp-Jvagd_AD7yNyuIUNahByDQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/~~J71UieQOQlumHrcdA8XIpg==/com.app.myapp-Jvagd_AD7yNyuIUNahByDQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/system_ext/lib]]
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1392)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7183)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:284)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2284)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8399)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.game.soulmate.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~J71UieQOQlumHrcdA8XIpg==/com.app.myapp-Jvagd_AD7yNyuIUNahByDQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~J71UieQOQlumHrcdA8XIpg==/com.app.myapp-Jvagd_AD7yNyuIUNahByDQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/~~J71UieQOQlumHrcdA8XIpg==/com.app.myapp-Jvagd_AD7yNyuIUNahByDQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/system_ext/lib]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1227)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1384)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7183) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:284) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2284) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8399) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068) 
                                                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/react/ReactApplication;
                                                                                                            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                                                                                                            ... 15 more
                                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
                                                                                                            ... 18 more
```